# Stop counting if a character can't be found in map

Tags: c++, math, roman-numerals

I've got an assignment in which I've to create a roman numeral to integer converter. As my code stands, I've just used a map to relate characters to integer values, which are added to a sum, accounting for values like IV etc. For strings that do not wholly consist of roman numerals, I've been trying to make it stop adding as soon as a character without a mapped value is found but I'm running into issues.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

map<char, int> num;
num.insert({ 'I', 1});
num.insert({ 'V', 5});
num.insert({ 'X', 10});
num.insert({ 'L', 50});
num.insert({ 'C', 100});
num.insert({ 'D', 500});
num.insert({ 'M', 1000});

string str;

while(getline(cin,str)){

    int sum = 0;

    transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::toupper);

    for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++){

        if (num.count(str[j]) != 1){
            break;
        }


        if (num[str[j]] < num[str[j+1]]){
            sum += num[str[j+1]] - num[str[j]];
            j++;
            continue;
        }

            sum += num[str[j]];
    }

    cout << sum << "\n";
 }
 return 0;
}
```

I thought that num.count(str[j]) would return 0 if a mapped value wasn't found, and then I could use that to break the for loop but I'm wrong somewhere. When I give the command line argument of iittii, I would want it to output a sum of 2 (as it would stop when it encounters the first t) but instead I get 4.

Is my implementation incorrect or is there an alternative method to achieveing this?

Thank you

Comment: `break` only breaks out of the inner-most loop.  If you want to break out of both loops, then set a flag and then test-and-break after the loop.  Or wrap your loop stuff up in a function so you can check the result and then break.  Conveniently, one such function already exists for you: `std::any_of`.

Comment: str[j+1] is UB, so your program has random behaviour

Comment: Unrelated. Don't use `int` type for a index, it is a signed type. `str.length()` returns an unsigned type (`std::size_t`), and mixing types of different signedness is never a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with your following block of code:

```
if (num[str[j]] < num[str[j+1]]){
    sum += num[str[j+1]] - num[str[j]];
    j++;
    continue;
}
```

That block of code causes your program to malfunction because it has 2 issues:

1. It incorrectly calculates the `sum`.
2. It may cause your program to crash unexpectedly at some point (i.e.
   segmentation fault) because the code `str[j+1]` means that the
   index `j+1` is greater than the length of
   `str` at the end of the for loop when `j = str.length - 1`. In other words, this means that the index `j+1` is running out of bound at that point.

So, after I've  modified that block of code as shown below, your program works correctly:

```
    if (j > 0 &&
        num[str[j]] > num[str[j-1]]){
        sum += num[str[j]] - 2 * num[str[j-1]];           
        continue;
    }
```

Here is my new program (with my new block of code):

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

map<char, int> num;
num.insert({ 'I', 1});
num.insert({ 'V', 5});
num.insert({ 'X', 10});
num.insert({ 'L', 50});
num.insert({ 'C', 100});
num.insert({ 'D', 500});
num.insert({ 'M', 1000});

string str;

while(getline(cin,str)){

    int sum = 0;

    transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::toupper);

    for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++){

        if ( num.count(str[j]) < 1 ){
            break;
        }

        // HERE IS MY NEW BLOCK OF CODE :-)
        if (j > 0 &&
            num[str[j]] > num[str[j-1]]){

            sum += num[str[j]] - 2 * num[str[j-1]];           
            continue;
        }

            sum += num[str[j]];
    }

    cout << sum << "\n";
 }
 return 0;
}
```

---

Please let me know if the answer above works for you.

I have run 2 test cases and verified the program works:

1. Input = `iittii`

   Per your description of the problem, I enter the input `iittii`
   as you require, and my program produces the correct output `2` as
   you expect.
2. Input = `IV, IX, CD`

   In addition, I have also tested the input such as IV, IX, CD as user
   @ArminMontigny described, and my new code works correctly.